# \includepdf not working correctly, gives invisible text

Tags: pdfpages

`\includepdf{mypdf}` returns a blank page. The text is there, however it is not visible. 
If i make a new blank tex file, the pdf will load properly.

However, removing all packages except `pdfpages` does not solve the problem, nor does clearing the cache. I'm using overleaf to compile my files.

Non of the errors mentioned by the compiler are related to the included pdf.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWtyz.png):[image: Text is invisble but can be selected]

Text is invisble but can be selected.
The actual pdf to be displayed is seen below...

[image: The actual pdf to be displayed]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I think it will be hard to help without a reproducable example document or at least a link to your Overleaf project.

Comment: Have you tested that this is not an artifact of the overleaf PDF viewer? aka have you tried downloading the PDF and viewing it in a different viewer?

Comment: Yes I have downloaded the file, but the problem is still there.

Comment: I think this will allow you to view the project;
https://www.overleaf.com/read/nfwrzkxyxtkh

Comment: Ah the pdf becomes visible if I remove \makecover[split]